# Constraint Violation (NOT NULL) when using merge but not persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have been encountering some unexpected behavior when using JPA.

In my data model, I have two entities, `Foo` and `Bar`.  `Foo`s and `Bar`s actually have a many-to-many relationship--but each occurrence of a `Bar` in a `Foo` also contains additional information which has caused us to eschew a simple JoinTable approach.  Therefore, we use another entity, `FooBar`, to represent the occurrence of a `Bar` within a `Foo`.  Here are examples.  (Please note I have omitted everything except the relationship members/methods).

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = FooBar.FOO,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   private Set<FooBar> fooBars = new HashSet<>();

   public void addFooBar(Collection<FooBar> fooBars)
   {
       Set<FooBar> previous = new HashSet<>(this.fooBars);
       this.fooBars.addAll(fooBars);
       for ( FooBar fooBar : fooBars )
       {
           if ( !previous.contains(fooBar) )
           {
               fooBar.setFoo(this);
           }
       }
   }

   public void removeFooBar(FooBar ... fooBars)
   {
       removeFooBar(Arrays.asList(fooBars));
   }

   public void removeFooBar(Collection<FooBar> fooBars)
   {
       Set<FooBar> previous = new HashSet<>(this.fooBars);
       this.fooBars.removeAll(fooBars);
       for ( FooBar fooBar : fooBars )
       {
           if ( previous.contains(fooBar) )
           {
               fooBar.setFoo(null);
           }
       }
   }

   public Set<FooBar> getFooBars()
   {
       return Collections.unmodifiableSet(fooBars);
   }
}

@Entity
public class Bar
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = FooBar.BAR,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   private Set<FooBar> fooBars = new HashSet<>();


   public void addFooBar(FooBar ... fooBars)
   {
       addFooBar(Arrays.asList(fooBars));
   }

   public void addFooBar(Collection<FooBar> fooBars)
   {
       Set<FooBar> previous = new HashSet<>(this.fooBars);
       this.fooBars.addAll(fooBars);
       for ( FooBar fooBar : fooBars )
       {
           if ( !previous.contains(fooBar) )
           {
               fooBar.setBar(this);
           }
       }
   }

   public void removeFooBar(FooBar ... fooBars)
   {
       removeFooBar(Arrays.asList(fooBars));
   }

   public void removeFooBar(Collection<FooBar> fooBars)
   {
       Set<FooBar> previous = new HashSet<>(this.fooBars);
       this.fooBars.removeAll(fooBars);
       for ( FooBar fooBar : fooBars )
       {
           if ( previous.contains(fooBar) )
           {
               fooBar.setBar(null);
           }
       }
   }

   public Set<FooBar> getFooBars()
   {
       return Collections.unmodifiableSet(fooBars);
   }
}

@Entity
public class FooBar
{
    public static final String FOO = "foo";

    public static final String BAR = "bar";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
               optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = FOO,
                nullable = false)
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
               optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = BAR,
                nullable = false)
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo getFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        // If we are no longer associated with a previous report, we must
        // remove ourselves from it.
        Foo previous = this.foo;
        if ( null != previous && !previous.equals(foo) )
        {
            previous.removeFooBar(this);
        }

        // Next, we need to set our own value.
        this.foo = foo;

        // Finally, we need to make sure that we're added to the new report
        if ( null != this.foo && !this.foo.equals(previous) )
        {
            this.foo.addFooBar(this);
        }
    }

    public Bar getBar()
    {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar)
    {
        // If we are no longer associated with a previous report, we must
        // remove ourselves from it.
        Bar previous = this.bar;
        if ( null != previous && !previous.equals(bar) )
        {
            previous.removeFooBar(this);
        }

        // Next, we need to set our own value.
        this.bar = bar;

        // Finally, we need to make sure that we're added to the new report
        if ( null != this.bar && !this.bar.equals(previous) )
        {
            this.bar.addFooBar(this);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem arises when I have a pre-existing `Foo` and `Bar`, but want to make a new `FooBar` referencing them.  Currently, our DAO implementation provides a method `dao.createOrUpdate` which uses `entityManager.merge`.  However, this call will fail with a null check violation.  If, however, I manually access the entity manager and use `entityManager.persist`, I have found that everything works properly.  Here is some test code:

```
public class Example
{
    private static final Logger LOG =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);

    @Test
    public void failWithMerge()
    {
        // Make a Foo and a Bar that already exist.
        Long fooId;
        Long barId;
        try ( ExampleDAO dao = new ExampleDAO() )
        {
            EntityManager manager = dao.getEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setFooValue("This is a foo value");
            fooId = manager.merge(foo).getId();

            Bar bar = new Bar();
            bar.setBarValue("This is a bar value");
            barId = manager.merge(bar).getId();

            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        // Make a new FooBar to associate them
        Long id;
        try ( ExampleDAO dao = new ExampleDAO() )
        {
            EntityManager manager = dao.getEntityManager();

            Foo foo = dao.getOne(Foo.class, fooId);
            Bar bar = dao.getOne(Bar.class, barId);

            FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
            fooBar.setFoo(foo);
            fooBar.setBar(bar);

            LOG.info("============ MERGE ============");
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            id = manager.merge(fooBar).getId();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            LOG.info("===============================");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void worksWithPersist()
    {
        // Make a Foo and a Bar that already exist.
        Long fooId;
        Long barId;
        try ( ExampleDAO dao = new ExampleDAO() )
        {
            EntityManager manager = dao.getEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setFooValue("This is a foo value");
            fooId = manager.merge(foo).getId();

            Bar bar = new Bar();
            bar.setBarValue("This is a bar value");
            barId = manager.merge(bar).getId();

            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        // Make a new FooBar to associate them
        Long id;
        try ( ExampleDAO dao = new ExampleDAO() )
        {
            EntityManager manager = dao.getEntityManager();

            Foo foo = dao.getOne(Foo.class, fooId);
            Bar bar = dao.getOne(Bar.class, barId);

            FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
            fooBar.setFoo(foo);
            fooBar.setBar(bar);

            LOG.info("============ PERSIST ============");
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.persist(fooBar);
            id = fooBar.getId();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            LOG.info("=================================");
        }
    }
}
```

By enabling additional log output, I have discovered that, when using `merge`, it is actually attempting to insert the `FooBar` twice!  Here is the pertinent log output when using `merge`:

```
1609 [main] INFO my.example.Example - ============ MERGE ============
1610 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        FooBar
        (id, bar, foo, info, version) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
1610 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
1610 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
1610 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>
1610 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 0
1612 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        FooBar
        (id, bar, foo, info, version) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
1612 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - <null>
1613 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - <null>
1613 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>
1613 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 0
1614 [main] WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL     Error: -10, SQLState: 23502
1614 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -     integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10097 table:     FOOBAR column: BAR
1616 [main] INFO my.example.Example - ===============================
```

Contrast that with this output which results from using `persist`:

```
1636 [main] INFO my.example.Example - ============ PERSIST ============
1636 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        FooBar
        (id, bar, foo, info, version) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
1636 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 2
1636 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 2
1637 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>
1637 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 0
1642 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    update
        Foo 
    set
        fooValue=?,
        version=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
1642 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - This is a foo value
1643 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
1643 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 2
1643 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 0
1645 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    update
        Bar 
    set
        barValue=?,
        version=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
1646 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - This is a bar value
1646 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
1646 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 2
1646 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding     parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 0
1646 [main] INFO my.example.Example - =================================
```

We had made the decision to use `merge` in our DAO implementation for several other reasons, and I would much prefer to find a way to make this work correctly using `merge`.  I'm hoping that one of you might provide some insight.

Finally, for what it's worth, our JPA provider is Hibernate--though as you can see I have limited myself to JPA annotations in this example.  My tests are running in HSQLDB, while our production code uses PostgreSQL.

Thanks,

Curtis

**Update**

I think what I'm going to end up doing is altering the implementation of `dao.createOrUpdate` (which is what uses `merge`).  What's not included above is that `Foo`, `Bar`, and `FooBar` all provide the `getId()` method.  Therefore, I think I'm going to do this:

```
public <T extends PersistentObject> T createOrUpdate(T object)
{
    if ( null == object.getId() )
    {
        manager.persist(object);
        return object;
    }
    return manager.merge(object);
}
```

(`PersistentObject` is a common interface for all of the objects).